# How add asynchronously version SimpleCassandraRepository to spring data cassanbdra?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

[Spring data cassandra](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/) project has org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository class for resolving cassandra repositories.

What I want:

1. Create "general" interface for exmaple `AsyncCassandraRepository` like `org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.TypedIdCassandraRepository` but with asynchronous methods.
2. Create implementation for that interface - like org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository, but with asynchronous methods.
3. Then create new asynchronous repositories for other domain entities just extends from async inteface e.g. `CustomerRepository extends AsyncCassandraRepository`. So no new implementation will be needed.

So the idea is to create new async interface and implementation and used it everywhere. SimpleCassandraRepository itseft is really simple, so no problem to create new async version.

The **real problem** is to "register" new async interface and implementation into spring data cassandra depths. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [jira task](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-144) in spring data cassandra project: